# Codeigniter Ajax sorting search result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

**Controller:**

```
public function index()
{
   .
   .
   .

   $search_result = $this->m_results->search_people(array('country'=>$country,'state'=>$state,'city'=>$city,'sort'=>$this->sort,'id'=>$data['id']),$keyword,$s_id);

   $this->load->view('include/header',$data);
   if($search_result != FALSE)
   {
       $data['results']['freelancers'] = $search_result;
             // print_r($data['results']['freelancers']); exit();
       $data['sort_value'] = $this->sort;
       $this->load->view('search',$data);
   }else{
       $data['string'] = $this->input->post('keyword');
       $this->load->view('search_empty',$data);
   }
       $this->load->view('include/footer',$data);
}
```

**Ajax function:**

```
$("body").on("change", "#sort", function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: "get"
        , url: base_url + "search"
        // , cache: false
        , data: {
            skills: $("#inputtags").val()
            , sort: $("#sort").val()
            , city: $("#locationTextField").val()
        }
        , success: function (data) {
            // console.log(data);
            alert(data);
            $("body").html(data);
        }
    })
});
```

**View:**

```
   <div class="form-group sidemargin">
        <select name="sort" id="sort" class="form-control select color2 bold">
                <option value="rating" <?php echo set_select('sort','rating',( $sort_value == "rating" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Ratings</option>
                <option value="review_count" <?php echo set_select('sort','review_count',( $sort_value == "review_count" ? TRUE : FALSE )); ?>>Reviews</option>
        </select>
   </div>
```

Above are the code I'm using for display the results after sorting by Ajax. But now the problem is after sorting the result, when I alert the success `data` its coming the entire html code but not the result from database.

I can't understand why its showing the html code instead of the sorted data from db. When I try to `print_r()` those result in controller, its showing correct value. When it come to Ajax `success` the values are different.

So folks help me to solve this. Answers will are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can `$this->load->view('include/header',$data);` and `$this->load->view('include/footer',$data);` in your controller be the reason? Your controller seem to load a complete page with header and footer.

Comment: Yes. That is the reason, but I have no idea why its coming on `success`.

Comment: Is that the controller that your ajax request is calling? If yes, you're loading the complete page, which is what your ajax request is retrieving. The `success`-callback get's what ever you output in the controller. If you output  the header and the footer, the success-callback will get that. If you don't want to get the header and footer, don't load the header and footer.

Comment: Thanks. I understood.